# Changing jQuery button size and location

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/132/

As you can see the button on the left box takes up the whole `div`, I want the button to be a little button on the top right corner in the box. with a onclick handler that `alert("clicked")` when clicked. Do I have to create a new `div`?

Code for the button :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#1" ).button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-folder-open"},        
        text: false
    });
});
```

And right now if I mouse over the left box, it shows the bean's conditions in a weird way.. why isn't it showing it like the right box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SEE THIS WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/133/)

Basically, you're applying the button to the wrapping element, which forces it to be the size of the container.  In my fiddle, I added a new div inside the #1 container, called .button_wrap and apply the button to it instead.  Lastly, I added a click event to the new .button_wrap class for the alert.

As a side note, I know its just a fiddle, but I would avoid all those inline styles in a production enviroment.

NEW JS AT BOTTOM OF FIDDLE:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#1 > div.wrap > div.button_wrap" ).button({
        icons: {primary: "ui-icon-folder-open"},

        text: false
});
    $('.button_wrap').on('click', function(e){
       alert('clicked'); 
    });
});
```

NEW CSS:

```
.button_wrap {width:16px;height:16px;float:right;}
```

NEW HTML STRUCTURE OF FIRST BOX:

```
<div class="normal" id="1"
    style="text-align:left;
    top:  13em;
    left: 5em;
    height: 10em; 
    width: 12em;">
    <div class = "wrap">
        <div class="button_wrap"></div>
    <div class = "show">
        <strong>Bean 1
        <p>Status: Normal</p>
        </strong>           
    </div>
    <div class = "noshow">
        <P>0001: Normal</P>
        <P>0002: online</P>
        <P>0003: online</P>
        <P>0004: online</P>                         
    </div>

    <div class = "here">
        <P>0001: online</P>
        <P>0002: online</P>
        <P>0003: online</P>
        <P>0004: online</P>                         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Rooster, is it possible to make it not display the 0001, 0002...information when I mouse over the button? Right now it shows all that when I mouse over the button and get ready to click the button. 
I want it only to show all that when mouse over the box (not the button)

Comment: @JennyC yeah, you'd just add another wrapper div around .wrap, move the button holding div outside of wrap, and change the function that initializes the button to point at the new css position.  http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/137/